Backstage - HTTP error 400 when creating component
Am trying to create a component in Backstage. Below is the template file which I use:
apiVersion: scaffolder.backstage.io/v1beta3
kind: Template
# some metadata about the template itself
metadata:
  name: v1beta3-demo
  title: Test Action template
  description: scaffolder v1beta3 template demo
spec:
  owner: backstage/techdocs-core
  type: service

  # these are the steps which are rendered in the frontend with the form input
  parameters:
    - title: Fill in some steps
      required:
        - name
      properties:
        name:
          title: Name
          type: string
          description: Unique name of the component
          ui:autofocus: true
          ui:options:
            rows: 5
    - title: Choose a location
      required:
        - repoUrl
      properties:
        repoUrl:
          title: Repository Location
          type: string
          ui:field: RepoUrlPicker
          ui:options:
            allowedHosts:
              - gitlab.com

  # here's the steps that are executed in series in the scaffolder backend
  steps:
    - id: fetch-base
    ...
    - id: publish
      name: Publish
      action: publish:gitlab
      input:
        allowedHosts: ['gitlab.com']
        description: This is ${{ parameters.name }}
        repoUrl: ${{ parameters.repoUrl }}

    - id: register
      name: Register
      action: catalog:register
      input:
        repoContentsUrl: ${{ steps['publish'].output.repoContentsUrl }}
        catalogInfoPath: '/catalog-info.yaml'

When try to create the same, I get the below error

I believe the URL formation is fine. Would be great, if I get some advice on the same?

You could start debugging by using curl to replicate the API request that the publish:gitlab action is sending. You might get a sense of why it's a Bad Request from that.

@DavidTuite Thanks for your reply. I have checked the same and found the issue was on my side. In the input field, I was not giving the correct value

I have found the issue. In the Repository field, I was giving the full GitLab URL, instead of the repo name
Wrong value: https://gitlab.com/< org name >/< repo name >
Correct value: < repo name >

